# PHP array to correct json format

Tags: php, arrays, json, highcharts

I have this array:

```
$users = Array
(
[Gareth] => Array
    (
        [25732] => 180
        [25689] => 2310
        [25760] => 
        [25759] => 
        [25758] => 
        [25728] => 
        [25734] => 
    )
[Adam] => Array
    (
        [25732] => 
        [25689] => 
        [25760] => 
        [25759] => 
        [25758] => 420
        [25728] => 60
        [25734] => 
    )
[Cennydd ] => Array
    (
        [25732] => 
        [25689] => 
        [25760] => 
        [25759] => 
        [25758] => 
        [25728] => 
        [25734] => 1035
    )
)
```

It has users with ids of work and the duration they've spent on that work in minutes.

I need to output this data using `highcharts` so it needs to be in a Json format.

Currently, using `json_encode`, it returns:

```
{ "Gareth":
  {
    "25732":180,"25689":2310,"25760":null,"25759":null,"25758":null,"25728":null,"25734":null
  },
  "Adam Jukes":
  {
    "25732":null,"25689":null,"25760":null,"25759":null,"25758":420,"25728":60,"25734":null
  },
  "Cennydd":
  {
    "25732":null,"25689":null,"25760":null,"25759":null,"25758":null,"25728":null,"25734":1035
  }
}
```

But I need this in the format:

```
[{
    "name": 'Gareth ',
    "data": [180, 2310,null, null, null,null, null]
    },
    {   "name": 'Adam',
    "data": [null, null, null,null,420, 60, null]
    },{
    "name": 'Cennydd',
    "data":[null, null , null, null, null,null, 1035 ]
    }]
}]
```

But I can't seem to figure it out.
Do I need to use a `foreach` to separate and create a new array with the right format?

Comment: Where do you get the first array from ?

Comment: You have to convert php array to the desired format befor encoding it to JSON

Comment: you'll have to iterate over your data and reformat a new array from it ... what else ?

Comment: It's a combination of 2 arrays. 
Because sql wouldn't return a row if they didn't have a duration I use two other arrays to create this array. One array has a list of all the work Ids, the second has the users Id and duration and inputs the duration next to the id if it is present, or leaves it null if not present.
The data I'm getting back in my new array is exactly what I need, just not in the correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get what you want would be to modify the way you retrieve your `$users` array, but if you can't, here would be the way to reformat it to fit your need :

```
$new_users = array();

foreach ($users as $user => $data) {
    $new_users[] = array(
        'name' => $user,
        'data' => array_values($data)
    );
}

echo json_encode($new_users);
```

Comment: @Shamrockonov explain 'almost'. I expect my answer might help

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'm after, however, in the "data" array, I need to exclude the keys and just have the values.
E.g {"name":"Gareth Cole","data":{"25732":180,"25689":2310,"25760":null,"25759":null,"25758":null,"25728":null,"25734":null}}"
becomes
{"name":"Gareth Cole","data":{180,:2310,null,null,null,null,null}}"

Comment: @Shamrockonov yup, thought so

Comment: @Shamrockonov I edited my post, look at `array_values`

Answer (score 1):

You can itterate the array and use array_values to get the format you require:

```
$fixed=array();
foreach ($users as $k => $v) {
    $fixed[]=array('name'=>$k, 'data'=>array_values($v));
}

echo json_encode($fixed);
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for also, Just didn't see your answer first. Thanks anyway. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to format your Array after encode it to JSON.

```
$result = array();
foreach($users as $k => $v) {
       $result[] = array(
         'name' => $k,
         'data' => $v
       );
}
```

And finally

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Why are you using two loops ?

Comment: Because you use Array of Arrays

Comment: And ? With `foreach` there is no need to loop through the first and second array. You can do it with only one loop.

Comment: No problem ;) was just sayin'